# Pygame set_pos and get_pos doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm working on my own music player using pygame and tkinter. I have those 2 functions:

```
def update_scale_info(self):
        if self.selected_song:
            total_time_seconds = pygame.mixer.Sound(self.selected_song).get_length()
            slider_value_total = total_time_seconds
            audio_length_minutes = total_time_seconds // 60
            total_time_seconds %= 60
            if self.manual_time_set_flag:
                current_time_seconds = self.manual_time_set
                pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(current_time_seconds)
                self.manual_time_set_flag = False
            else:
                current_time_seconds = int((pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() + 1) / 1000)
            slider_current_time_seconds = current_time_seconds
            current_time_minutes = current_time_seconds // 60
            current_time_seconds %= 60
            self.starttime_label.config(text=f"{int(current_time_minutes):02d}:{int(current_time_seconds):02d}")
            self.endtime_label.config(text=f"{int(audio_length_minutes):02d}:{int(total_time_seconds):02d}")
            self.Scale.config(from_=0,to=int(slider_value_total))
            self.Scale.set(int(slider_current_time_seconds))    
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_scale_info)

    def on_scale_move(self, event):
        if self.selected_song:
            total_time_seconds = pygame.mixer.Sound(self.selected_song).get_length()
            current_time_seconds = int((self.Scale.get() / 100) * total_time_seconds)
            pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(int(current_time_seconds))
            self.manual_time_set = int(current_time_seconds)
            self.manual_time_set_flag = True
            self.starttime_label.config(text=f"{int((current_time_seconds)//60):02d}:{int((current_time_seconds)%60):02d}")
```

The current issue is the slider and get_pos and set_pos. I move the slider, music moves to proper place, the slider after 1s moves back to where it was and updates from the start, even though the sound was moved forward. I'm using a wav file.
set_pos doesn't really work. get_pos does it's own thing and starts from the beginning. Sorry if not everything was clarified, but I will be happy to explain further, if anyone is able to support me.

I used flags, global timers that could maybe manipulate the value, but nothing helped. All I want is a slider that when moved, updates the position thorugh set_pos and plays the audio from the selected place.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: https://github.com/kayteckk/Python_WAV_player/blob/main/wav.py
This is how the code looks like.
When I import a song it plays, updates the label and slider position. When I move the slider it does forward the music itself, but the label and slider get back to previous position after one second (which is due to: self.root.after(1000, self.update_scale_info))